# Bi-Lipschitz classification of germs of conformal metrics at a singularity

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, conformal-geometry

First let me introduce some definitions.

- By a *germ of conformal metrics at a singularity*, or simply a *germ*, I mean a conformal Riemannian metric $g$ defined on a punctured neighborhood $U$ of $0$ in $\mathbb{C}$. Two germs are considered the same if they coincide on some punctured neighborhood of $0$.
- A germ $g$ is said to be *complete* if $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}d(z, z_0)=+\infty$ for any $z_0\in U$, where $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the distance induced by $g$.
- To germs are said to be *bi-Lipschitz* if their proportion is bounded from above and below by positive constants (on some punctured neighborhood of $0$).

A lemma in [a paper of Benoist and Hulin](http://www.math.u-psud.fr/~benoist/prepubli/11projective.pdf) (Lemma 5.2 therein) implies the following highly nontrivial result:

> **Theorem.** All germs with pinched negative curvature (i.e. with curvature bounded from above and below by negative constants) are bi-Lipschitz to each other.

One can prove this theorem by adapting the arguments in that paper: first extend  germs to complete conformal metrics on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ with bounded curvature, then apply Generalized Maximum Principle of Omori-Yau. This proof seems somewhat unnatural, since it uses a strong global theorem while the problem is purely local.

**Questions.** Does there exist similar results in the literature about bi-Lipschitz classification of complete germs? Is there a more direct proof of the above theorem?